# ¿Por qué me devuelve -inf/inf como resultado del algoritmo en c++?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Hola agradecería su ayuda, aun soy algo nueva en esto. Hasta ahora hice esto pero solo me arroja la ultima raíz, los demás resultados los marca como inf o -inf, no importa cuantas ecuaciones meta solo me arroja el ultimo resultado, todo los demás los marca como inf, seria de gran ayuda para mi si pudieran ayudarme a solucionar el problema porque ya llevo un rato en esto y no me queda.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    char salir;
    int n, i, j, k;
    float factor, suma;
    float a[30][30], b[30], x[30];
    cout << setprecision(4);
    cout << fixed;
    cout << "\nELIMINACION GAUSSIANA"
         << "\n"; // Eliminacion gaussiana
    printf("\n");
    do {
        cout << "Numero de ecuaciones: ";
        cin >> n;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                printf("Coef. (%i,%i) ", i + 1, j + 1);
                scanf("%f", &a[i][j]);
            }
            printf("Termino independiente Ec. %i: ", i + 1);
            scanf("%f", &b[i]);
        }

        cout << "\nMATRIZ"
             << "\n"
             << endl;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                cout << " " << a[i][j];
            }
            cout << " " << b[i];
            cout << endl;
        }
        for (k = 0; k < n - 1; k++) {
            for (i = k + 1; i < n; i++) {
                factor = a[i][k] / a[k][k];
                for (j = k; j < n; j++) {
                    a[i][j] = a[i][j] - factor * a[k][j];
                }
                b[i] = b[i] - factor * b[k];
            }
        }

        x[n - 1] = b[n - 1] / a[n - 1][n - 1];
        for (i = n - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
            suma = b[i];
            for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                suma = suma - a[i][j] * x[j];
            }
            x[i] = suma / a[i][j];
        }

        cout << "\nMATRIZ ESCALONADA\n";
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                cout << " " << a[i][j];
            }
            cout << " " << b[i] << "\n";
        }
        cout << "\nSOLUCION\n";
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cout << x[i] << "\n";
        }
        cout << "\nDeseas salir s/n: ";
        cin >> salir;
    } while (salir != 's' && salir != 'S');
    return 0;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en uno de los últimos for.

```
for (i=n-2; i>=0; i--)
{
    suma=b[i];
    for(j=i+1;j<n; j++){
        suma=suma-a[i][j]*x[j];
    }   

    x[i]=suma/a[i][j]; // Aquí
}
```

Si prestas atención, al salir del ciclo `j` vale `n`. Pero esa posición queda fuera del rango con el que estás trabajando. Además la matriz no está completamente inicializada. Así que si ejecutas varias veces el código obtendrás diferentes resultados.

La posición correcta es `i`. Te queda así:

```
for (i = n - 2; i >= 0; i--)
{
    suma = b[i];
    for(j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        suma -= a[i][j] * x[j];

    x[i] = suma / a[i][i];
}
```

---

Nota que habrá matrices sin solución como esta:

```
1 0 0 1
0 1 0 0
0 1 0 1
```

Obtendrás que la última incógnita puede valer infinito y como el cálculo de las demás depende de las otras, también `nan`.

Antes de hacer el cálculo podrías simplemente verificar si el coeficiente de la última incógnita es distinto de 0. Si es 0, hay dos casos. Uno en el que hay infinitas soluciones (el termino es 0) y otro en el que no existe solución (el termino independiente es distinto de 0). Así:

```
if (a[n - 1][n - 1] != 0) {
    x[n - 1] = b[n - 1] / a[n - 1][n - 1];
    for (i = n - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        suma = b[i];
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            suma -= a[i][j] * x[j];
    
        x[i] = suma / a[i][i];
    }

    cout << "\nSOLUCION\n";
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << x[i] << "\n";
}
else {
    if (b[n - 1] == 0)
        cout << "Multiples soluciones\n";
    else
        cout << "Sin soluciones\n";
}
```

---

Quería mencionar que existen los [operadores compuestos](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment#Builtin_compound_assignment) como `+=`, `-=`, `*=` y `/=` que te permiten escribir de forma más simple una operación. Específicamente cuando haces una operación sobre una variable y actualizas su valor al resultado.

Por ejemplo:

```
suma += 5;

// Equivale a esto
suma = suma + 5;
```

También sugiero que le des nombres descriptivos a tus variables y separes el código en algunas funciones para poder reutilizar el código y facilitar la lectura. Por ejemplo:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void cargarEcuaciones(int &n, float matriz[30][30], float terminos[30]){
    cout << "Numero de ecuaciones:\n";
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cout <<"Coef. (" << i + 1 << ", " << j + 1 <<"):\n";
            cin >> matriz[i][j];
        }
        cout << "Termino independiente Ec." << i + 1 << ":\n";
        cin >> terminos[i];
    }
}

void imprimirMatriz(int n, float matriz[30][30], float terminos[30]){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
             cout << matriz[i][j] << " ";
         
         cout << terminos[i] << "\n";
    }
}

void escalonarMatriz(int n, float matriz[30][30], float terminos[30]){
    for (int k = 0; k < n - 1; k++) {
        for (int i = k + 1; i < n; i++) {
            float factor = matriz[i][k] / matriz[k][k];
            matriz[i][k] = 0;
            
            for (int j = k + 1; j < n; j++)
                matriz[i][j] -= factor * matriz[k][j];
            
            terminos[i] -= factor * terminos[k];
        }
    }
}

bool calcularSolucion(int n, float matriz[30][30], float terminos[30], float soluciones[30]){
    if (matriz[n - 1][n - 1] == 0)
        return false;

    soluciones[n - 1] = terminos[n - 1] / matriz[n - 1][n - 1];
    for (int i = n - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        float suma = terminos[i];
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            suma -= matriz[i][j] * soluciones[j];
        
        soluciones[i] = suma / matriz[i][i];
    }

    return true;
}

int main() {
    char salir;

    int n, i;
    float matriz[30][30], terminos[30], soluciones[30];

    cout << setprecision(4);
    cout << fixed;
    cout << "\nELIMINACION GAUSSIANA\n";
    
    do {
        cargarEcuaciones(n, matriz, terminos);

        cout << "\nMATRIZ\n";
        imprimirMatriz(n, matriz, terminos);
        
        escalonarMatriz(n, matriz, terminos);

        cout << "\nMATRIZ ESCALONADA\n";
        imprimirMatriz(n, matriz, terminos);

        if (calcularSolucion(n, matriz, terminos, soluciones)){
            cout << "\nSOLUCION\n";
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                cout << soluciones[i] << "\n";
        }
        else {
            if (terminos[n - 1] == 0)
                cout << "\nMúltiples soluciones\n";
            else
                cout << "\nSin soluciones\n";
        }
        
        cout << "\nDeseas salir s/n:\n";
        cin >> salir;
    } while (salir != 's' && salir != 'S');
    return 0;
}
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##rVZfb9owEH/3p7gxqYW2tPxp@zD@SFFbTUgtlUb7so4HL5j2IHGQnWzTJr7YXvfBmJ2YxCaAhjQQEJ/Pd7@7390Zf7Gov/r@avUeuR8kEwZdjELKcdEntkjGgtGwT0gikb8CpyGTC@ozkPGkQ8i3CCfgU/FKxZ2fUB8jzmQVeQxH/AymQURjCGks8OdLuzHWn7U0ZiJEHkktq/0ioF5@lMTQ7UJlmIRMRKAQsNzohy@80snUkEO/DzxbTSMBqUOEHjQ66qertgBPT2uQmXW0ZpnWLNOauVoWiMpNxKbnUK1oQAin0EyRnUEqmBlBpVbAyg1k8EzUOH6ZjQuFJdnwA5WnLBGAfMIWjE@Q8ZjBnX@@4dr1ZLzkWUTjZEmWhhUMFwJDFA8pkDT4wyn5t@zuS6@TmzxqOztpdGBnkZT0rThT9TwXRbxM@jSIOP1PAc@zSOY6EqhDUz3uKCmdmrmmaWd6tHbqcEr9WB3rWfHPx3CxXs710q0mR1EjcnZdFzYJBtBOIhzTioN6bw3uxEIzG@/xZ3NiH8/l81Lhp2x9jaJAzYzATwIqRlGQ6AY/lK61TJrzzCYRp1A1JlLuxuYHeiqDRSIEixPBFfBAMjXLtMgytz5SuDWSnC7H9pZppDdauij6We/U6079ZPiTkNo@0MqZQyjuJzS1U@@5pJ7Y8dhc5g/WPupYUzMXlpVirhArZbFIVMaUTKMLKfLqOjL/jQqQNEBhMmp4RZOfrfS6xLqUGjPrQSBZvBDMR6lr5rLWcTan@INNXJGaFHf3g4fB0LsZPA7ho/c8Gg28oZcPkPRrElnElK4zBT9DXCCtGVgbrh68p0@Dz86g3hjD222VeNkcZodCgLvRjXf/OPRuvcPRFNqqj0qNuuWMzVmttvU@1dBGj/fPmoXSlZkVeumGKU2svAicqnXuA/eSZaqzNwaxjmmzo92xsC2pf34HMS4CJi3fpTC0t31WRurO3nF8WS4B6@Atk4zKrK1AXvCtfwVM06XW4PsbBgyq2Yl3PTiWx3B0BMV6dGzKznS0uliWq1WbNKGh3k2iPvqJNNJ1g3DSJpdwBdfQUjotuIRrcqW@W9Am8i8).

Answer (score 0):

El problema radica en el for:
El factor esta eliminandose y al final se guarda el valor 0 y al dividir ya te sale el inf

```
for (k=0;k<n-1;k++){
        for (i=k+1;i<n;i++)
        {
            factor=a[i][k]/a[k][k];
            for (j=k;j<n;j++){
                a[i][j]=a[i][j]-factor*a[k][j];
            }
            b[i]=b[i]-factor*b[k];
        }
    }
```